# How to change text for an "a" element when clicked and clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get an "a" element to change text when clicked once and once again when it is clicked again or if another "a" element is clicked. Here is the code I have so far:

```
         $(document).ready(function() {

            $("a").click(function() {

               $(this).prev().toggle();
        
               if ($(this).val("Show More") {
                  $(this).text("Show less");
               }        
               else if ($(this).val("Show less")){
                 $(this).text("Show more");
               }
        
            });
         });
```

Comment: An `<a>` has no `value` to use `val()` on....only form control elements have value. Even if it did you are using it incorrectly in the `if()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to know if that element's text content when clicked is "Show more" or "Show less" to set it the other way. So you should check for `text()` function and then set it like you are doing. Leaving it like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    
    if ($(this).text() === "Show more") {
    $(this).text("Show less");
    }       
    else if ($(this).text() === "Show less"){
    $(this).text("Show more");
    }
    
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your logic to work with `text` because `a` has no value per se.

Also you could rely on some class or data-attribute if the logic with text seems too fragile

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle();

    $(this).text(function(_, text){
      return {
        'Show More': 'Show Less',
        'Show Less': 'Show More'
      }[text]
    })
  });

});
```

```css
.content {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<a>Show More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like charlietfi mentioned in his comment.. An `<a>` Tag does not have the `val()` Function.

So if you must compare the current Text of your element. If you want to do it like i said, your code should look like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let current_text = $(this).text();
  let new_text;
  
  if(current_text === 'Show more') {
    new_text = 'Show less';
  } else {
    new_text = 'Show more';
  }
  
  $(this).text(new_text);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML === "Show more" ? "Show less" : "Show more"        
    });
});
```